# pandas - skiprows and nrows how to combine?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large CSV file, around 11G. I want to read parts of the file, perform some calculations and move to the next chunk.

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/location/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=1000000)
```

I get the same rows i.e. first `nrows`.

I thought this would get me a a slice from 1,000,001 to 3,000,000 rows.

I wanted to keep the header, so I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/location/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=(1, 1000000))
```

Header was retained, but still getting the same rows i.e. first 2,000,000 rows.

### Edit

I need overlapping slices/chunks:

```
# First select: 2 M rows
df = pd.read_csv('/location/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000)

# Next select row 1M to 3M

df = pd.read_csv('/location/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=1000000)

# Next select row 2M to 4M

df = pd.read_csv('/location/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=2000000)



#and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include header row in the list `skiprows`, and make it as an iterable with all rows you do want to skip:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/locaiton/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=range(1, 1000000))
```

Example with a simple CSV file:

```
A,B
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

Keeping headers, skipping the first 4 data rows, and reading the next 3 rows:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=3, skiprows=range(1,5))

   A  B
0  5  5
1  6  6
2  7  7
```

I think this simple approach can be generalised to your use case:

```
# read first 2M rows
df = pd.read_csv('/locaiton/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=range(1, 2))

# read from 1M to 3M
df = pd.read_csv('/locaiton/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=range(1, 1000001))

# read from 2M to 4M
df = pd.read_csv('/locaiton/of/file/2016/Q.csv', nrows=2000000, skiprows=range(1, 2000001))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('<your file name here>', skiprows=1000000, chunksize=2000000)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to clarify the question a bit. I need overlapping chunks. More clarity in question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify with a `lambda` function which rows do you want to skip, as doc states.

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv("f.csv", nrows=2000000, skiprows=lambda x: x in range(1, 1000000))
```

This will skip rows specified by index, and the number of rows parsed is between 0 and `nrows`, because skip has precedence over taking `nrows`.

Example:

```
x,y
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

```py
# there are 4 rows
>>> pd.read_csv("f.csv", skiprows=lambda x: x in range(1, 8), nrows=5)
    x   y
0   7   7
1   8   8
2   9   9
3  10  10
```